# How to append elements of a recordlist when iterating over a list of records?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
TYPE visit AS RECORD
(
  DATA_1 VARCHAR2;
)
TYPE lstVisit IS TABLE OF visit;
BEGIN
 FOR I IN LISTA.FIRST..LISTA.LAST LOOP
  FOR J IN LISTB.FIRST..LISTB.LAST LOOP
    lstfetchdata:=function_fetchdata(LISTA); 
  END LOOP;
   lstVisit:= lstfetchdata;
 END LOOP;
```

Now the issue I am facing is how to store all the elements in lstVisit.
Suppose the function fetchdata() returns 3 rows and in the subsequent call returns 2 and so on.
How should i index lstVisit to store all the values one after another

Comment: Your pseudocode is a bit unclear; what are LISTA and LISTB, and what is LISTB adding to the example - or is the function supposed to be taking the current element of both of those, rather than the whole of LISTA? How are the `lstVisit` and `lstfetchdata` variables defined are they both of `lstVisit` type (which is at best confusing naming)?

Comment: @AlexPoole LISTA and LISTB are two similar list types of RECORD

Answer (score 0):

For each record returned by the function call, you can extend your final `lstVisit` collection, and assign the fetched record to that position; something like:

```
  -- initialise the final collection
  lstVisit := new tabVisit();

  -- loop over both existing collections
  for i in lista.first..lista.last loop
    for j in listb.first..listb.last loop
      -- get a subset of values
      lstfetchdata:=function_fetchdata(lista(i), listb(j));
      -- loop around that subset
      for k in 1..lstfetchdata.count loop
        -- extend the final collection and add the subset value
        lstVisit.extend();
        lstVisit(lstVisit.count) := lstfetchdata(k);
      end loop;
    end loop;
  end loop;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=195212e5796d60c5cafa7eb4b9fb8cd8) with some name changes and a made-up function to generate random strings based on the lista/b values, but should give you the idea.